# TypeError: _normalizr.schema is undefine

Tags: normalizr

When using normalizr I'm getting the error "TypeError: _normalizr.schema is undefine"

I am using normalizr for the first time. I have tried several samples from the normalizr doc and a couple of other places but get the same error.

Here is the example I'm trying to run when getting the above error:

```js
import { normalize, schema } from 'normalizr';

const myData = {
  users: [
    { id: 1 },
    { id: 2 },
  ],
};

const user = new schema.Entity('users');
const mySchema = {
  users: [ user ],
};

const normalizedData = normalize(myData, mySchema);

console.log(normalizedData);
```

My project is using node & webpack with babel-preset-es2015 and normalizr ^2.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation you're following is for normalizr v3.x. You should upgrade if you plan on continuing using it.